# Scanner does not determine number as long or not

Tags: java

Im trying to experiment on this code i found.  If you enter two consecutive numbers(separated by space), the first number is identified as long but the second is not.

```
import java.util.*;

public class ScannerDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   String s = "Hello World! 35 62 + 3.0 = 6.0 true ";
   Long l = 13964599874l;
   s = s + l;

   // create a new scanner with the specified String Object
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s);

   // find the next long token and print it
   // loop for the whole scanner
   while (scanner.hasNext()) {

   // if no long is found, print "Not Found:" and the token
   System.out.println("Not Found: " + scanner.next());

   // if the next is a long, print found and the long 
   if (scanner.hasNextLong()) {
   System.out.println("Found: " + scanner.nextLong());
   }

   }

   // close the scanner
   scanner.close();
   }
}
```

Result:

```
Not Found :Hello
Not Found :World!
Found :35
Not Found :62
Not Found :+
Not Found :3.0
Not Found :=
Not Found :6.0
Not Found :true
Found :13964599874
```

**Why is 62 not found?**

Comment: Have you tried to use debug and step by step to see what happen? *62* is read by scanner.hasNext() and the the next statement is printing *Not Found*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the not found code under else, like this:

```
// if the next is a long, print found and the long 

    if (scanner.hasNextLong()) {
        System.out.println("Found :" + scanner.nextLong());
    }else{
       System.out.println("Not Found :" + scanner.next());
    }
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. just wondering, does the sequence of the conditions matter(in this case)? isn't it that when a condition is not met, it will go to the next and so on? hope you can clear this out as well. blessings

Comment: @gendave Sequence of conditions matter but in your case , this condition was getting executed:  System.out.println("Not Found: " + scanner.next()); without any conditional check. Since it was not inside any conditional block, it was getting executed always, thereby moving the reference to next item.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the "Not found" line needs a conditional such as

`if (!scanner.hasNextLong())`

Currently, that line of code is getting the next element on each iteration whether the element is a long or not. That's why 62 is not being detected but 35 is. After the 35 is found by the second statement with the conditional, 62 is being processed by the first statement.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to look at each word in your string and filter out only the tokens that can be made into Longs

```
    String s = "Hello World! 35 62 + 3.0 = 6.0 true ";
    Long l = 13964599874l;
    s = s + l;
    Long temp;

    for (String word : s.split("\\s+"))
    {
        if (word.length()>10 && word.length() < 20) {
            try{
            Long.parseLong(word);
            System.out.println(word+ " is a Long");

            }catch(IllegalArgumentException ex){

            }
        }

    }
```

output:

```
13964599874 is a Long
```

With this you also eliminate signed integers. Only pulling the Long types

Comment: the long is not recognized if you add a long inside the String s